# Aggregate intra-day data

Tags: mysql, netbeans-7

I have stock data stored @ frame 1 minute, so that 1 row = 1 minute, and I am using this query to get min, max, sum, first and last record for each day.

I have 511 1 minute rows for every day (from 0900 up to 1730).

```
SELECT  MAX(high), MIN(low), SUM(volume) from a2a where date = 20131202; 
SELECT open FROM a2a ORDER BY time LIMIT 1;
SELECT close FROM a2a  WHERE time = 1730 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1; 

SELECT  MAX(high), MIN(low), SUM(volume) from a2a where date = 20131203; 
SELECT open FROM a2a ORDER BY time LIMIT 1;
SELECT close FROM a2a  WHERE time = 1730 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT  MAX(high), MIN(low), SUM(volume) from a2a where date = 20131204; 
SELECT open FROM a2a ORDER BY time LIMIT 1;
SELECT close FROM a2a  WHERE time = 1730 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

In Netbeans, this returns 9 tabs:

My questions are:

1) Is there a way to get these results in a single tab?

2) Do I need to execute 3 different select per day, or is there a way to accomplish that in a single query?

3) Is there a faster way than this to compute these aggregates? What's posted is just as example, I need to get hundreds of daily data.

**Edit:** table a2a image. date and time type are CHAR, ope to close are DOUBLE and volume is INTEGER.

[image]

Comment: Please give us the description of your a2a table, including the data types of your `date` and `time` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the open and close using correlated subqueries:

```
  SELECT symbol, date, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
         (select open from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time limit 1) as open,
         (select close from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time desc limit 1) as close
  FROM a2a a1
  GROUP BY symbol, date
  ORDER BY symbol, date;
```

An index on `a2a(symbol, date, time)` would speed this query.

Comment: 1) how to modify this query if I would need to aggregate data only to get last 100 daily bars? Now it works perfectly but it aggregates all data available in database.
And, 2) How to get data aggregated for weekly, or aggregate in 5 minute data?

Comment: @Albertoacepsut . . . You should ask another question, with this answer as the starting point.

Comment: ok done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046648/weekly-and-intraday-data-aggregate

Answer (score 2):

Try this for the high / low / volume

```
 SELECT symbol,
        date,
        MAX(high)    AS dailyhigh,
        MIN(low)     AS dailylow,
        SUM(volume)  AS dailyvolume
  GROUP BY symbol, date
```

You'll get one row per day per symbol.

It's hard to tell how you handle opening price. Surely the first timestamp in your whole table, even without date, is not the right method.  So, let us figure out the earliest timestamp for each date.

```
 SELECT symbol,
        date,
        MIN(time) AS opentime
   FROM a2a
  GROUP BY symbol, date
```

Now, we need to look up the opening price for that timestamp.  How to do that? It's made a little more complex because you might have more than one row for that particular time and date for that issue.

```
 SELECT a.symbol, 
        a.date,
        AVG (a.open) AS dailyopen
   FROM a2a a
       JOIN (
         SELECT symbol,
                date,
                MIN(time) AS opentime
           FROM a2a
          GROUP BY symbol, date 
        ) AS b   ON a.symbol = b.symbol 
                AND a.date = b.date
                AND a.time = b.opentime
  GROUP BY a.symbol, a.date
```

This pulls out the opening records (the lowest-time records) for each symbol and date.

Now, it looks to me like your closing records are the records that have timestamp 1730, or the latest record that has a timestamp less than 1730.  This is turning from snappy SQL into real work, but these are financial records and Madoff is in jail, so let's do it right. Here's the closing time for each symbol on each date.

```
 SELECT symbol,
        date,
        MAX(time) AS closetime
   FROM a2a
  WHERE time <= 1730
  GROUP BY symbol, date
```

Now we need the closing price for each symbol on each date. We'll retrieve that the same way we retrieved the opening price.

```
 SELECT a.symbol, 
        a.date,
        AVG (a.close) AS dailyclose
   FROM a2a a
       JOIN (
         SELECT symbol,
                date,
                MAX(time) AS closetime
           FROM a2a
          WHERE time <= 1730
          GROUP BY symbol, date
        ) AS b   ON a.symbol = b.symbol
                AND a.date = b.date
                AND a.time = b.closetime
  GROUP BY a.symbol, a.date
```

The next step is to join these three summary queries together, and limit the date range you're handling.

```
SELECT d.symbol, d.date, d.dailyhigh, d.dailylow, d.dailyvolume,
       o.dailyopen,
       c.dailyclose
  FROM (
      /* the first summary query, daily high low volume */
       ) AS d
  JOIN (
      /* the second summary query, daily open */ 
       ) AS o ON d.symbol = o.symbol AND d.date = o.date
  JOIN (
      /* the third summary query, daily close */ 
       ) AS c ON d.symbol = c.symbol AND d.date = c.date
 WHERE d.date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%Y%m%d') 
   AND d.date  < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
 ORDER BY d.symbol, d.date
```

This will give you three days' worth of data, ending with yesterday.  You have to cut and paste your three summary queries into this big fat join. I'm kind of hoping you will do that, because formatting deeply nested queries like that is not much fun.

This isn't simple, but it's very robust and explicit about your business rules.

Comment: But you'll need to extend it slightly to get first and last

Comment: @Strawberry, slightly?  :-)  this stuff is real work.

Comment: @Ollie, thank you very much, a little bit tricky for me but I will study it carefully.

Comment: @Albertoacepsut you are welcome. You will figure it out I am sure.