# Weekly and intraday data aggregate

Tags: mysql

I have this query to perform intraday data aggregation into daily data (thanks to Gordon Linoff).

I store stock market data 1 minute per row, I have 511 1 minute rows for every day (from 0900 up to 1730). I use MySQL vers 5.6.11

Data is as picture below

[image]

```
SELECT symbol, date, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
     (select open from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time limit 1) as open,
     (select close from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM a2a a1
GROUP BY symbol, date
ORDER BY symbol, date;
```

My questions:

1) how to modify this query if I would need to aggregate data only to get last 100 daily bars?

2) How to get data aggregated into weekly, or aggregate into 5 minute data?

**Edit:** This version works on weekly aggregation (and monthly aggregation too using month instead of week)

```
SELECT symbol, date, week(date), MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
 (select open from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and week(a1.date) = week(a2.date) order by time limit 1) as open,
 (select close from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and week(a1.date) = week(a2.date) order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM a2a a1
WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 100 week)
GROUP BY symbol, week(date)
ORDER BY symbol, date;
```

I still have something to fix:

1) first query about daily aggregation returns 100 calendar days, not 100 daily aggregated rows. I need to get 100 records sorted starting from most recent backward. Same for weekly aggregation where I need 100 weekly records.

2) What about 5 minutes or n minutes aggregation? In example, aggregate from 0900 up to 0904, then from 0905 up to 0909 etc.for 5 min aggregation

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the last 100 daily bars?  If you mean the last 100 days:

```
SELECT symbol, date, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
     (select open from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time limit 1) as open,
     (select close from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM a2a a1
WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 100 day)
GROUP BY symbol, date
ORDER BY symbol, date;
```

If you want another grouping, then you need to change the `group by` and correlated subquery to have the same expression.  For instance:

```
SELECT symbol, week(date), MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
     (select open from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.week(date) = a2.week(date) order by time limit 1) as open,
     (select close from a2a a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.week(date) = a2.week(date) order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM a2a a1
WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 100 day)
GROUP BY symbol, week(date)
ORDER BY symbol, week(date);
```

Comment: yes I meant last 100 days; executing your query I get this error
Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
GROUP BY symbol, date
ORDER BY symbol, date' at line 5
Line 1, column 1

Comment: @Albertoacepsut . . . The correct function is `date_sub()`, not `datesub()`.

Comment: @Gordon...Well first query now runs perfectly,I have only changed in limit 100; instead of WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 100 day) in order to get 100 daily aggregated rows. I get error on second query Error code 1630, SQL state 42000: FUNCTION a1.week does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
Line 1, column 1

Comment: @Albertoacepsut . . . The function `week()` has existed at least since  MySQL 5.0 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: @Gordon...see my update above: now it works for weekly aggregate